# In Jenkins what permissions are required for anonymous users to be able to start a job by a web hook?

Tags: jenkins, kiln

We have a Jenkins installation that uses the OpenID plugin to authenticate our company users.  The problem we have is that our source control (Kiln/Mercurial) pushes notifications to Jenkins either anonymously or via username/password.  As all users use OpenID I cannot use username/password.  So with that being said what is the minimum set of permissions for an anonymous user to be able to kick of a job build in Jenkins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use matrix-based security (or project-based matrix), the user needs to have the "build" column in the "job" group ticked.